# Windows Phone 7.1 (mango dev) - Code-first creating a SQL CE from delimited text

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1, csv

Alright, background:

I've got an app, it has a local read-only reference database (lets call it "local.sdf") included in the source.  Now, the user will be reaching out to a website (call it "http:\www.websiteImGettingTxtFrom.txt") which is the source for a pipe-delimited .txt file to update a separate local db ("webdata.sdf") with entities that will correspond directly with entities in local.sdf.  Ideally, it would be easiest if the app just created/updated webdata.sdf on app_launch/app_load/whenever the user pushed a button to "update".

So, how do I create/update the aforementioned webdata.sdf in-code strictly from a pipe-delimted txt (keeping in mind this database will have over 20,000 entities with, i believe, 7 properties each)?

here's an exmaple of the pipe-delimited text I'm pulling:

```
|ColumnName1|ColumnName2|ColumnName3|ColumnName4
|Entity|Value1|Value2|Value3
|Entity2|Value1|Value2|Value3
|Entity3|Value1|Value2|Value3
```

I know how to do a mass record clear, but populating is the real issue.  Also, is there a process-lite way to do all of this in background (to prevent the app from crashing the DB if the app is closed during the load)

Thanks,
rapterj

Answer (score 0):

You can include an webdata.sdf with an empty table as a resource, and copy to Isolated Storage on launch, if it does not exist already (the DataContext generated by SQL Server Compact Toolbox gives you a CreateDataIfExists method that can do that for you).

For the INSERTs, batch these in appropiate batches and call SubmitChanges (you will need to do some testing)

Comment: Alright, I get the CreateDataIfExists part, but lets assume for a minute that I have extremmely limited knowledge about how to deal with SQL CE DB and absolutely no clue how properly "batch" delimited text into said database (especially in a manner that allows me to check the date the database was last updated, so that if its the same day, it won't do the massive update (which would probably be a very time and process consuming mass delete/mass insert))...do you have a code example?